# Is there a way to access HTTP GET variables without $_GET

Tags: php, http

Is there a way to access HTTP GET variables in PHP without using `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`? I'm asking because I know that `$_POST` isn't populated if the POST isn't sent through a form and I want to make sure that using `$_GET` doesn't have similar problems.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Sure, you could post manually (such as with AJAX) using the `$_POST` method, and get then check `$_POST` variable.

Comment: @Dai $_POST has the problem of being unavailable if you aren't submitting a form. I wanted to research $_GET and alternatives to $_GET in case it has a similar problem.

Comment: Why dont you explain what you are trying to achieve, you might get a solution faster

Comment: You can check if the `$_POST` or `$_GET` is populated with `if(isset($_GET['abc'])){}` - or first filter it with `filter_input()` and then check with the `empty()` function/method. With `isset()` you can check if it's "available". It's not exactly what you asked... But i don't get it why you want to know what you asked, so i posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains the raw `foo=bar&baz=qux` type string, which you can pull apart with `parse_str()` and the like. But why would you want to? You'd just be replicating work that PHP has already done for you.

Comment: I think better use `urldecode` instead of `parse_str()`

Comment: urldecode just does char translations, e.g. `+` -> space char. it doesn't convert the query string into key:value pairs in an array or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`filter_input()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function:

```
$search_html = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```